# Applications of derived categories to "Traditional Algebraic Geometry"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, derived-categories, birational-geometry

I would like to know how derived categories (in particular, derived categories of coherent sheaves) can give results about "Traditional Algebraic Geometry". I am mostly interested in classical problems. For example: moduli spaces problems, automorphism groups of varieties, birational classification of varieties, minimal model program and so on.

Furthermore, I would also be interested to know about theorems that are more aesthetically pleasing being stated in the derived category language. For instance, I think Serre duality can be generalised to singular varieties through derived categories.

Any reference about results is very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that a good example of the usefulness of the Derived Category of coherent sheaves for studying classical questions is the recent preprint by Soheyla Feyzbakhsh

[Mukai's program (reconstructing a K3 surface from a curve) via wall-crossing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06692),

where the author uses wall-crossing with respect to Bridgeland stability conditions in order to solve the classical Mukai problem of reconstructing a K3 surface from its hyperplane section.

Comment: As pointed out by dhy, this is *not* what is called Derived Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: I agree. This is intended as an answer to the second part of the question, since "we show how to reconstruct the K3 surface containing the curve C as a Fourier-Mukai transform of a Brill-Noether locus of vector bundles on C" is a pleasant statement expressed by using the derived category of coherent sheaves (at least in my opinion).

Comment: Sure, in mine too. In fact I think the derived category of coherent sheaves has many nice applications to classical geometry (see e.g. Kuznetsov's work). I am not sure about Derived Algebraic Geometry, I'd like to see some interesting answers to the question.

Answer (score 12):

The  global Torelli Theorem for cubic fourfolds says the following. Let $X_1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ and $X_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be smooth cubic fourfolds. The fourfolds $X_1$ and $X_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a Hodge isometry between $H^4(X_1,\mathbb{Z})_{pr}$ and $H^4(X_2, \mathbb{Z})_{pr}$. This was originally proved by Voisin (voir [Théorèmes de Torelli pour les cubiques de $\mathbb{P}^5$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389270)) using a subtle and delicate analysis of the restriction of the period mapping to the family of cubics containing a plane.

In 2019, Huybrechts and Rennemo gave a new proof of the Torelli Theorem for cubic fourfolds using derived categories (see [Hochschild cohomology versus the Jacobian ring and the Torelli theorem for cubic fourfolds](http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2019-1/2019-1-005.pdf)). The strategy of their proof is the following:

$\bullet$ We first assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are very general in the moduli spaces of cubic fourfolds.

$\bullet$ The derived category $D^b(X_1)$ and $D^b(X_2)$ contains $K3$-categories, say $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$.

$\bullet$ Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are very general, a result by Addington and Thomas ensures that there exists actual $K3$ surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $\mathcal{A}_i \simeq D^b(S_i)$.

$\bullet$ The very specific Hodge structure of a cubic fourfolds show that any isometry between $H^4(X_1,\mathbb{Z})_{pr}$ and $H^4(X_2,\mathbb{Z})_{pr}$ induces an isometry between the spaces $H^{\bullet}(S_1,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^{\bullet}(S_2,\mathbb{Z})$ (endowed with the Mukai pairing). Orlov's derived Torelli Theorem then implies that $D^b(S_1) \simeq D^b(S_2)$.

$\bullet$ Huybrechts and Rennemo show that this equivalence commutes with the auto-equivalence given by twisting sheaves by $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

$\bullet$ They deduce that there is an isomorphism $\operatorname{HH}(\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{O}(1)) \simeq \operatorname{HH}(\mathcal{A}_2, \mathcal{O}(1))$, where $\operatorname{HH}(\mathcal{A}_i, \mathcal{O}(1))$ is a variant of the Hochschild-cohomology ring of $\mathcal{A}_i$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

$\bullet$ They show that there is a ring isomorphism $\operatorname{HH}(\mathcal{A}_i, \mathcal{O}(1)) \simeq J(X_i)$, where $J(X_i)$ is the Jacobian ring of $X_i$.

$\bullet$ The Mather-Yau Theorem allows to conclude that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are isomorphic.

This proof is not necessarily way shorter than the original one by Voisin, but it suggests a shift on perspective that has been very fruitful since. Torelli type Theorems for hypersurfaces of dimension $n$ which degree $d$ divides $n+2$ should be stated using some variant of the Hochshild cohomology (with coefficients) of the Kuznetsov component of the derived category of the hypersurface. These *categorical Torelli* type results/conjectures have been studied quite carefully recently.