# Results relying on higher derived algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

Are there any results in number theory or algebraic geometry whose statement does not involve either higher categories or any derived structures but whose most natural (known) proof uses derived $n$-Artin stacks for $n>1$? We are using Toen--Vezzosi terminology.

EDIT: the $n$-Artin stack in question should not to be obtained as the quotient of the constant groupoid associated to a $(n-1)$-Artin stack. I did not specify this initially, my fault, but I think the requirement is pretty natural. Neither of the two answers I can see at the time of the edit address this point.

Comment: Derived categories (of quasicoherent sheaves, of sheaves of $D$-modules, of etale sheaves ...) are simultanously higher and derived.  Do they count?

Comment: @CharlesRezk do they prove any result in number theory or algebraic geometry whose statement does not involve either higher categories or any derived structures?

Comment: If derived categories are going to count, then this question suggests an answer (and I'm sure there are others in the same vein): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321852/applications-of-derived-categories-to-traditional-algebraic-geometry/321879#321879 . However, I would have thought this is not what you had in mind. It is certainly not what I would call derived geometry. Also, people usually study derived categories of coherent sheaves as a triangulated category, i.e. forgetting the higher structure to some extent.

Comment: To a certain extent, all derived geometry is necessarily "higher'", for example in the sense that the functor of points of a derived scheme must take values in the $\infty$-category of spaces. Perhaps you want "derived" to mean only using derived schemes as opposed to derived stacks, and "higher" to refer to (not necessarily derived) $\infty$-stacks?

Comment: @SamGunningham I see there might be some confusion about what "higher" means. We will focus on higher derived stacks then (which are a more or less well-defined notion, I think). "Derived" can mean "derived Artin 1-stack", in our question.

Comment: @CharlesRezk by "make sense" I mean to find outside applications of the unification of two approaches he proposes. If you do not see how is that relevant, that is OK.

Comment: I am very confused by this question. Would the solution to the Weibel conjecture count?

Comment: @op, tamagawa number formula by lurie gaitsgory, heavily used dg ind schemes, factorization cohomology etc. If "construct a good elliptic cohomolgy theory" counts as such a problem, then Lurie again. Iirc the Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze work uses E_inf rings a lot, there's some topological cyclic homology in there etc.

Comment: @EBz I think BMS does not use higher derived stacks. Not sure about the moduli interpretation of elliptic cohomology, maybe it does fit the bill.

Comment: @op, also I think it's important to remember sam gunninghams comment, you're already doing "higher" stuff when u do derived stuff, the functors already take values in inf-gpds. Not to mention, if you work with derived schemes of course the "higher" versions will show up occasionally, as some functors won't be representable the way u want them to

Comment: @EBz the question is not about general "higher" stuff, it is specifically about higher derived stacks. If you can give an example where these functors won't be representable, that might qualify as an answer.

Comment: @DenisNardin What are you very confused about? I am not competent enough to judge about Weibel's conjecture, but a quick inspection of the article suggests that it does not count.

Comment: @op, am I to understand that u want an instance of an X in a paper which has pi_0(X) an honest (n>0)-stack? If such doesn't exist in lurie ell-cohom it would be a miracle. Indeed the naive def of "family of ell curves  over a dg scheme" leads to one immediately if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @EBz fine then, if you can show that that is the case, post it as an answer, I will upvote.

Comment: A derived stack which takes values in 1-grpds is just an ordinary stack. So there are no "non-higher" derived stacks. If you're just looking for an application of derived stacks, most of the above qualify, also try e.g. Arinkin-Gaitsgory on geometric Langlands conjecture.

Comment: @crystalline I am not sure I understand. Toen defines the notion of "derived 1-Artin stack" https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2012/04/dag-ems.pdf

Comment: @crystalline do you claim all derived 1-Artin stacks are underived? Could you provide a proof for me, a novice?

Comment: @schematic_boi derived $n$-Artin stack ≠ $n$-truncated derived Artin stack. Different ways to set up the induction, see p. 75 of http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/DAG.pdf (Lurie takes the $n$-truncated approach which is different from Toen's).

Comment: @crystalline ok, thanks, I see now, I will clarify the question then.

Comment: I think I get it now: you want examples of $n$-Artin stacks for $n>0$, and where $n$-Artin is defined as in Toen's paper? Yes, this is a reasonable question but please clarify.

Comment: @crystalline yes, just was clarifying.

Answer (score 17):

Here is an example from Bhargav Bhatt's talk "Using DAG" at MSRI last week. Needless to say, any mistakes are mine.

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a coherent (quasi-compact and quasi-separated) scheme, let $A$ be a ring complete with respect to an ideal $I\subseteq A$. Then
$$ X(A) \to \varprojlim_n X(A/I^{n+1}) $$
is bijective.

Before going into the proof, let us consider the case $X$ is affine. Then 
$$
X(A) = {\rm Hom}(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X), A) = \varprojlim_n {\rm Hom}(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X), A/I^{n+1}) = \varprojlim_n X(A/I^{n+1}) . $$

The idea for the general (coherent) case is to replace $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ with ${\rm Perf}(X)$, the category of perfect complexes on $X$.

**Slogan.** Affine schemes have "enough functions". Coherent schemes have "enough vector bundles (perfect complexes)".

The second idea may be due to Thomason.

More precisely, we have:

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes.

(a) If $X$ is affine, then 
$$ {\rm Hom}(Y, X) \to {\rm Hom}(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X), \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)) $$
is bijective.

(b) If $X$ is coherent, then
$$ {\rm Hom}(Y, X) \to {\rm Hom}({\rm Perf}(X), {\rm Perf}(Y)) $$
is an equivalence.

We must specify what (b) means (here is where DAG enters the picture). We consider ${\rm Perf}(X)$ as the symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category of perfect complexes on $X$ (complexes locally quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of locally free sheaves of finite rank). The ${\rm Hom}$ on the right means the $\infty$-groupoid (space) exact $\otimes$-functors. So in particular (b) implies that this space is discrete. The map in (b) sends $f$ to $f^*$, the pull-back functor.

*"Proof" of Theorem.* We repeat the proof of the affine case, replacing rings with categories of perfect complexes:
$$
X(A) = {\rm Hom}({\rm Perf}(X), {\rm Perf}(A)) = \varprojlim_n {\rm Hom}({\rm Perf}(X), {\rm Perf}(A/I^{n+1})) = \varprojlim_n X(A/I^{n+1}) . $$
Unlike in the affine case, the middle equality needs some justification, which I am not ready to give.

**End remarks.**

(1) I think Bhargav mentioned that an idea due to Gabber allows one to get rid of the assumption that $X$ is coherent in the Theorem.

(2) He also said that the above proof is the only one he is aware of.

(3) Reference for the above (thanks to the user *crystalline*):

Bhargav Bhatt *Algebraization and Tannaka duality* [arxiv.org/abs/1404.7483.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7483.)

Comment: This doesn't actually use DAG, only higher categories. Key word is Tannaka duality, reference for the above: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7483.

Comment: Thank you! I thought looking at $X$ through the symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category ${\rm Perf}(X)$ counts as a use of DAG, though indeed, derived schemes do not make an appearance.

Comment: Certainly very derived techniques, just not DAG in the sense of the question.

Answer (score 7):

The derived moduli stack of perfect complexes $RPerf$ is a derived Artin stack which admits a filtration by open sub stacks $RPerf^{[a,b]}$. The latter is a derived $(b-a+1)$-Artin stack. See:

> Moduli of objects in dg-categories. Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Serie 4, Volume 40 (2007) no. 3, pp. 387-444. doi : 10.1016/j.ansens.2007.05.001. http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_2007_4_40_3_387_0/

This derived stack plays a critical role in the recently hot topic of shifted symplectic structures and shifted deformation quantization, see:

> Pantev, T., Toën, B., Vaquié, M. et al. Publ.math.IHES (2013) 117: 271. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10240-013-0054-1

Comment: Wrt applications to classical stuff, existence of symmetric obstruction theories in certain classical (obstructed!) moduli problems (typically DT type moduli of sheaves stuff)

Comment: @EBz you mean that is needed to define the virtual fundamental class to define counting invariants?

Comment: Is it a theorem that $RPerf^{[a, b]}$ is a strict $(b-a+1)$-Artin stack, i.e. not obtained as the quotient of the constant groupoid associated to a $(b-a)$-Artin stack?

Comment: @op, I mean that it is used to do so in a uniform and v natural way. Whether it is "needed" I couldn't say, it's certainly not equivalent to it so I guess not.

Comment: There are classical approaches to the VFC (can define the obstr. thry by hand) but as EBz said you get a symm. obstr. thry for free if you have a quasi-smooth der stk w/ (-1) shifted symp. structure.

Comment: @schematic_boi Not sure I get the question; $RPerf^{[a,b]}$ is definitely not $(b-a)$-Artin if that's what you're asking. Even think about $RPerf^{[0,0]}$, it's 1-Artin but obviously not 0-Artin. And $RPerf$ itself is not even close to being 1-Artin.

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, you category is well-defined once I fix the coefficient field. I take $k=\mathbb{Q}$. How to see that $RPerf^{[0, 1]}$ is not 1-Artin?

Comment: @schematic_boi Being $n$-Artin places strong bounds on your stack. If I have the indexing right, say $X$ is $n$-Artin, then the functor $X : dRing \to sSet$, restricted to ordinary rings, takes values in $n-1$-trunc. spaces. Obviously that's not the case for $RPerf^{[0,1]}$ as perfect complexes of amplitude $[0,1]$ form an $\infty$-category that is not a $1$-category.